# How do I update the daemon and open port 18080?

Tags: daemon, update

I have tried to open port 18080, but still it says:

> No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 18080

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

[image]

---

Also, I am getting this message:

> Last scheduled hard fork time shows a daemon update is needed soon.

Comment: Your destination IP needs to be the *internal* IP of the machine running the daemon. Your screenshot shows an *external/public* IP. This is not required in any case; you can safely ignore the logs of "No incoming connections". And yes, you will need to update the daemon soon.

Comment: Thx for info jtgrassie.
Can you also tell me alittle about how to update the daemon..

Comment: As I said, you will need to update your daemon soon. Monero is about to release v0.15. Once it is released, you'll need to update.

Comment: Ahh oki that way, thx. for info. now I understand.